# Using Socialite-package for Linkedin login on laravel 5

Tags: php, oauth, laravel-5, linkedin-api, laravel-socialite

I'm currently try to use socialite to create authentication using LinkedIn but I create the App on LinkedIn and I add the callback URL on it like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/callback/linkedin
```

and on config/services.php i add:

```
'linkedin' => [
        'client_id'     => 'xxxxx',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxx',
        'redirect'      => 'http://localhost:8080/callback/linkedin',
    ],
```

I also create Routes and function (I **did this for facebook and google it works fine no problem there**)
But when i try to use it for LinkedIn i get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 92: Driver [linkedin] not supported.
```

NT: on Socialite package documentation they say that the package support linkedIn

> Official Documentation
>
> In addition to typical, form based authentication, Laravel also
>   provides a simple, convenient way to authenticate with OAuth providers
>   using Laravel Socialite. Socialite currently supports authentication
>   with **Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google, GitHub and Bitbucket**.

Comment: Socialite supports that but Linkedin is not built in. You can extend current socialite package with this: [socialiteproviders for LinkedIn](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/linkedin/)

Comment: @Sovon yes i find this solution already but it will not override other drivers of facebook and twitter and google ?

Comment: I've not tested it. But, hopefully it'll not. It'll extend only.

Answer (score 0):

**@Route**

```
//social links integrations
Route::get('/social/linkedin/redirect', 'SocialAuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('/social/linkedin/callback', 'SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**@Controller Code**

```
public function redirectToProvider() {

     return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->redirect();
}


public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request){

    try {
        $provider_user = Socialite::driver('linkedin')->user();
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $request->session()->flash( 'alert-danger', 'Invalid request data detected! please try again.' );
        return redirect( '/' );
    }

    dd($provider_user);

}
```